# How to Replace Argument in List for Prime Generator

Tags: python, list, replace, primes

So I have spent tonight working on putting together this Prime generator based on the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Here is the code:

```
n = input("What number do you want to calculate to? ")
import time
start = time.time()
def pr(l):
  ln = l+1
  p = range(2, ln)
  for k in p:
    f = range(k, ln, k)
    for f in f[1:]:
       if f in p:
          p.remove(f)
    return p
print pr(n)
end = time.time() - start
print "This took: ",end
```

I think the main thing I would like to do is speed it up a bit. I am pretty sure that changing the `p.remove(f)` function to something like `p[f] = 0` would speed it up, but that doesn't work.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Or is there an even faster was to do this?

Comment: Which language is this? Tag the language

Comment: yes, do `p=range(2,l+1); for k in range(2, Math.sqrt(l)+1): for f in range(k*k,l+1,k):  if f in p: p.remove(f);`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
def primes(n): # sieve of eratosthenes
    ps, sieve = [], [True] * (n + 1)
    for p in range(2, n + 1):
        if sieve[p]:
           ps.append(p)
           for i in range(p * p, n + 1, p):
               sieve[i] = False
    return ps
```

Please time it and let me know how it compares to your version.